# Type of process of a system of high specific heat interacting with a system of low specific heat

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider two systems A and B. Let the Molar Specific Heat Capacity of A be very, very, very, very great. The walls of (A+B) be of adiabatic nature from three sides and diathermal from another side (as in picture). A and B share a diathermal wall. Initially the temperature of A, B and Surroundings are the same. If we increase the temperature of surrounding then heat transfer will occur between surroundings and system B. Since A and B are separated by a diathermal wall then heat will also transfer from B to A thus increasing temperature of A. Let the heat exchanged by B be low in magnitude such that there will be an infinitesimal change in the temperature of A (because of the high Specific Heat Capacity of A).
Now my question is :

1. Is this an quasi-static process ?
2. Is this process reversible ?

[image]

Comment: The answers to your two questions are no and no.  Are you familiar with the Transient Heat Conduction equation?

Comment: @ChetMiller No, actually. Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: Is the system in equilibrium when it reaches its final state where the temperature of A has changed differentially, while the right boundary of B is raised a finite amount in temperature?  If I understand correctly, you are raising the temperature at the right boundary of B, and heat is being conducted through B to flow into A, correct?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes. Your intuition is correct.

Comment: How can the system be at equilibrium if the boundary of B is higher in temperature than the temperature of A?

Comment: @ChetMiller Sorry I didn't read your comment properly. The answer to the first part of your comment is no. The system A and B are "trying" to achieve equilibrium when a differential amount of heat is transferred. However, the temperature is raised at the right side of B (near the diathermal wall) and heat is made to flow into B then further into A.

Comment: If the final state is not an equilibrium state, how can you talk about the entropy change (since entropy is a thermodynamic equilibrium property)?

Comment: @ChetMiller My bad I didn't think of this. If I understood you correctly, then since A and B have varying temperature therefore they don't are in any equilibrium state and therefore the entropy change cannot be defined and thus the reversibility of the system cannot be predicted. That's the answer to the second part. What will be the answer for first part of the question ?

Comment: Whether or not it is quasi static depends on the thermal conductivity of B.  If the thermal conductivity of B is very low, the change experienced by A can be considered quasi static.

Comment: @ChetMiller Got it! Thanks for your responses. I guess these responses in a form an answer below will be useful for others as well ;)